# imagemagic composite and convert annotate in one command

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am trying to overlay other image and add some multiline text on existing image using imagemagic.

want to write like this image  where fb name profile picture caption will be writen over existing image http://image2.nametests.com/result_image/f7e10d6619542e1770f1bcac2352d635.jpg

Here is my command.Which produces faulty image.

my original image original.jpg size is 800x600 .i want to overlay small.jpg size 180 px over original.jpg and want to annotate. imagemagic performs the task with given  command without any error but output is funny.

here is my output     https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tup82.jpg

original image https://i.stack.imgur.com/owk0F.jpg

overlay image https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSQFR.jpg

```
convert logo: -resize x180  -gravity center  -crop 180x180+0+0  /path/small.jpg  composite -geometry +160+13 /path/original.jpg   /path/picture.jpg  /path/namefinal.jpg
```

any help will be greatly appreciated

Refer the attached image for clear details. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvic8.jpg

Comment: Please try and show what result you are expecting as your question is very hard to understand.

Comment: @MarkSetchell like meaww.com we are making facebook play.where users will upload his profile picture and i want to add that picture in one format like this and want to write some caption in final http://imgur.com/a/xCwIf

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot understand what you want to do. Please click `edit` underneath your question and make sure that the entire description is correct and that the all the images you start with and end with are correct.

Comment: @MarkSetchell updating in 2 minutes

Comment: @MarkSetchell please check once

Comment: So you start with a picture of the Northern Lights and some text asking about your personality and ImageMagick takes a rectangular picture of a wizard and lays it on top and it becomes round, then ImageMagick rubs out the original writing and writes something else and it ends up looking like a wizard with a blue bar on the right?

Comment: @MarkSetchell imagemagic will not rub. that format is like that in blank space imagemagic will overlay image and in blank area only imagemagic will annotate text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129518/discussion-between-steeve-and-mark-setchell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
convert background.jpg overlay.jpg -gravity center -geometry +0-30 -compose over -composite combined.jpg
```

If you have some overlay image that is larger than the center circle on your background image, then you should create a circular mask image with the size of the overlay image and mask the overlay so that the outside of the circle is transparent, then overlay that transparent image on the background.

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow. Please add some explanation to the command you provided or reference the used commands and switches in your text so that users may learn how to use the ImageMagick interface. Please also consider splitting up your first, very long, sentence into multiple, smaller sentences or an ordered list. Thank you in advance.